# How to change PHP extension in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to change index.php into index.abc (or index.aspx). I tried to change $config['index_page'], but can't. I only can remove index.php and add .abc behind url through $config['url_suffix'] = '.abc'; Please help me.

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.abc';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this suffix in

```
/application/config/config.php

$config['url_suffix'] = '.abc';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .htaccess and it should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.abc$ $1.php
```

and leave this one as it is / was

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: @thai6070 do you have mod rewrite enabled? Because it works for me

Comment: Yes, Mod rewrite has been enabled